# Not able to access Samba VM share after reinstalling Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, samba

I am using Windows 10 as my main OS and was having some permissions problems earlier (supposedly caused by OneDrive).  I have since reinstalled Windows and Virtualbox.  I have done a straight copy-and-paste of my virtual machines and have them operating more-or-less as desired.  The VM in question is running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Before I reinstalled Windows, I was able to access the SMB share on my Windows computer.  Now, I am not able to, despite the settings remaining the same.  It is not allowing or accepting the username I enter either, stating that I do not have the correct permissions to access the share.  According to my Webmin installation, the share I am using has read-write access for everyone.  However, I am able to access the webserver as normal through a browser and, obviously, can run the VM and manage it through Webmin.

Could anyone suggest to me what I could do to try to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I have just tried to access the same fileshare on another computer, and it has been able to log in to the share.  It is also able to write to files on the share.  That would leave the issue solely with my own computer.

Comment: "More or less" describe the less part.

Comment: No access to the SMB share, but I can access the webserver through a browser, I can access via FTP, etc.